# How to use ROUNDDOWN in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, rounding

I want to use ROUNDDOWN function.

When i tried using the following query,it gives me an error saying "'rounddown' is not a recognized built-in function name."

```
select rounddown(25.227,2)
```

My requirement is to rounddown the value to two decimals

for ex: for value 25.22789 result should be 25.22

and round up also

for ex: for value 25.22789 result should be 25.23

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `select round(25.227,2)`

Comment: This is roundup and how about rounddown?

Comment: where did you get that function name from?

Comment: Use FLOOR - SELECT FLOOR(your_field) FROM ....

Comment: @Paolo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634963.aspx

Comment: as stated in the documentation it's a DAX function and not a SQL server function; you have to go with the alternative methods you find in the answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use third parameter of [`ROUND()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) function to truncate and then `CONVERT()` it to `DECIMAL(x, 2)` to get rid of unwanted trailing zeros.

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1812)

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), ROUND(25.227, 2, 1)) RoundDown,
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), ROUND(25.227, 2, 0)) RoundUp
```

Results

```
| RoundDown | RoundUp |
|-----------|---------|
|     25.22 |   25.23 |
```

Comment: Actually, round up means that `25.222` should become `25.23`. I don't think this can be done using a single T-SQL function

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP provided that `25.22789` should be converted to `25.23` (as default), nothing about `25.222`.

Comment: Agree with @StanislovasKalašnikovas. This works for given OP example.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas that's not rounding *up*, that's the default rounding behaviour that can go either way. If you wanted to round arbitrary values *up*, you'd need a different function or formula.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas Actually not, OP asks two functions: `ROUNDDOWN` to round up to two decimal places with `CEILING` effect and `ROUNDUP` with `FLOOR` effect. Read carefully.

Comment: If `ROUNDUP` is needed as @EvaldasBuinauskas and @PanagiotisKanavos said so OP can use something like: `SELECT ROUND(22.22789 + 0.005, 2)`, also updated my answer with this suggestion.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I think OPs main issue is getting round down with decimal places. Round up means basically normal output of Round function.

Answer (score 12):

I think you are looking for either `CEILING()` or `floor()` function like

```
select CEILING(25.227) //results in 26
```

(OR)

```
select FLOOR(25.227) //Results in 25
```

**EDIT:**

> for ex: for value 25.22789 result should be 25.22

You can try like below

```
select round(25.22789, 2, 2)
```

Which will result in `25.22000`

Comment: This will round to integer only.

Comment: I think that's what OP looking for, though not exactly sure.

Comment: Your query returns `26`

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, given both the function name but OP needs `Floor` most probably.

Comment: I need post decimal values

Comment: Perhaps CEILING(25.227 *  100) / 100.0 and FLOOR(25.227 * 100) / 100

Comment: @Polux2 This should be correct answer. It does exactly what OP needs and keeps correct number format instead of making it a string.

Comment: The truncating form of ROUND provides the round-down functionality but `ROUND(25.222,2)` will *not* round up to 25.23. Don't think there is a way to round up excep using CEILING and multiplication

Answer (score 3):

**ROUND FUNCTION**

You can use `SELECT ROUND(@num, 2, 1)`

As per [**ROUND**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) description:

```
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
```

> When function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default),
>   numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0 is specified,
>   numeric_expression is truncated.

**RESULT**

```
25.22
```

---

**CHARINDEX and LEFT**

Alternatively you can use `CHARINDEX` and `LEFT` in following if you want to do `"ROUND DOWN"` and use simple `ROUND` to do `"ROUND UP"`

```
DECLARE @num DECIMAL(16,3) = 25.227

SELECT LEFT(@num,CHARINDEX('.',@num)+2) as [RoundDown],
       ROUND(@num,2) as [RoundUp]
```

**RESULT**

```
RoundDown   RoundUp
25.22       25.23
```

---

**UPDATE**

As per comments about `ROUNDUP` you can use in following:

```
SELECT ROUND(22.22289 + 0.005, 2) as [RoundUp1]
```

**RESULT**

```
25.23
```

---

**DEMO**

You can test it at <kbd>**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1818)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

For rounding down, just use some simple math (one decimal place farther than you want to round to):

`SELECT ROUND(25.22789 - 0.005, 2)`

OUTPUT 25.22

For rounding up, simply use ROUND:

`SELECT ROUND(22.22789, 2)`

OUTPUT 25.23

Comment: No need for the subtraction, ROUND accepts a third parameter to truncate (round down) to a specific number of digits

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll leave the answer as a generic solution (i.e. it will work for Oracle and possibly others).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use CAST:

```
    declare @num decimal(18,5) = 22.22719
    select @num, CAST(@num as decimal(18,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from the future.

Multiply it up, divide it back down?

```
declare @myroundednumber numeric(9,4)=25.227
select 'Original' version,@myroundednumber figure 
select 'Rounded Up',cast(ceiling(25.227 *100)/100 as decimal(9,2)) 
select 'Rounded Down',cast(floor(25.227 *100)/100 as decimal(9,2))
```